# raster calculator fail to sum?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, raster-calculator

I am having a question about the raster calculation as I am trying to create a tool which I want to link with my python script to sum weight rasters but if failed to do so. here is my code:
     #*the original code is very long so I will try to minimize to my questions  *

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:my workspace" 
from arcpy.sa import *
...
input_weights = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  ***#this is my weights: in model builder, the DATATYPE is the DOUBLE #***
input_weights2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)***#this is my weights:in model builder, the DATATYPE is the DOUBLE #***
RASTER_1 =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #my feature class
RASTER_2 =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4) # my feature class 
...

myraster  = EcuDistance(RASTER_1)
myraster2 = EcuDistance(RASTER_2)
weight =myraster*input_weights+myraster2*input_weights2
weight.save("xxx")
......
```

Every time the tool would stop at (weight =myraster*input_weights+myraster2*input_weights2) and it says error:*can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?*

so if I manually entered those weights like:

```
input_weights = .5
input_weights2 = .4
...
...
weight =myraster*.5+myraster2*.4
weight.save("xxx")
```

the tool worked perfectly.Is there something wrong with my code. Should I do a transformation for the weights from input of the tool

Answer (score 2):

It would help a couple of prints of inputs_weights and type(inputs_weights) because It seems that You are storing string variables instead of floats. Have You tried input_weigths = float(arcpy.get....)?

Comment: Absolutely correct - `arcpy.GetParamterAsText` returns a python `unicode` (a type of string) object.

Comment: You can also use input_weights = arcpy.GetParameter(0) etc. to collect the parameter as the object passed instead of converting the object to text. I'm not sure why ESRI does not advertise this method of gathering parameters, but I use it sometimes when I want the object passed instead of a string.